# Getting Error on CAGR formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, formulas, vba

I have a data file and i'm getting a stupid error like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybVz4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRJ6J.gif)

Does anyone news why I'm getting this error.

**=((F4/B4)^(1/4))-1**

F4 = my ending value
B4 = My beg value
4 = Number of year.. (Should 4 year) `
Please help..

Comment: The error is coming from your ending value being negative

Comment: @pnuts yes I should have been more specific

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Excel problem. You're trying to compute the root of a negative number and Excel justifiably responds with an error.

You cannot mathematically compute this without using [imaginary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number).

From a business perspective, only CAGR from -100% to +infinity% make sense. You simply should not try to compute a CAGR for base variables that may change inbetween positive and negative, because that doesn't make sense.